DateTime указывает не верное время
использую DateTime  для сохранения времени, но мне выдает результат на 2 часа меньше, на пк часовой пояс выставлен правильно, в чем может быть проблема?
Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
результат 15:41, хотя у меня сейчас 17:41(без учтения дня), в чем может быть проблема?

Ну вы же сами попросили универсальное время, UTC

Внимательно прочитайте название того, что вы вызываете. Utc - это не ваше локальное время. Напишите в гугле Coordinated Universal Time и сравните с тем, что вам выдает метод, а также узнаете что такое UTC. Если хотите локальное время, то просто .Now.
